# Notation for generated subsets in Venn diagram (sets "combinations" by operations)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I would appreciate it if anybody shows me the most compact mathematical notation for the following sets formed by operations, so the subscript is different in every "e"($e_A$, $e_B$, $e_C$ are different sets).

- ${e_{_{i}}}\cap\ {e_{_{i}}}\cap\ {e_{_{i}}}
  \ |_{i\in \{A,B,C\}}$
- ${e_{i}}\cap\ {e_{i}}\cap \ {{e^c}_{i}}
  \ |_{i\in \{A,B,C\}}$
- ${e_{i}}\cap \ {{e^c}_{i}} \cap \ {{e^c}_{i}}
  \ |_{i\in \{A,B,C\}}$

Ex: I've tried with ${e_{i}}\cap \ {{e^c}_{j}} \cap \ {{e^c}_{k}}\ |_{i,j,k\in \{A,B,C\}| i\neq j\neq k }$ for the last one, but I don't know if this is correct and if it's the most compact expression.

PD: I'm not asking about giving a number to each subscript but express without ambiguities the example above.

EDIT: What I want to say is, there are the following sets, $e_A$,$e_B$,$e_C$ and I need to say, for example, $e_A \cap e_B \cap {e^c}_C$, $e_B \cap e_C \cap {e^c}_A$, $e_C \cap e_A \cap {e^c}_B$. Then how can I write this?
${e_{i}}\cap\ {e_{j}}\cap \ {{e^c}_{k}}
\ |_{i,j,k\in \{A,B,C\}\ \wedge\ i\neq j \wedge j\neq k \wedge i\neq k}$ ?

Maybe it's a really simple question, but thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this? If the sets are $E_1,$ $E_2,$ $\ldots,$ $E_n,$ then you can label the "Venn diagram parts" by the $2^n$-many $n$-digit binary numbers. For example, $0110$ means $E_1^c \cap E_2 \cap E_3 \cap E_4^c$ (i.e. elements not in $E_1$ and in $E_2$ and in $E_3$ and not in $E_{4}).$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you so much, but I don't want the "corresponding combination", it's more like the correct notation what I'm looking for

Comment: "Correct notation" depends a lot on context, which you haven't given. For example, none of your versions clearly indicate to what extent you are considering an informal list of sets (e.g. like saying "sets A, B, and C" in a sentence) as compared to desiring to formally denote a certain set of sets (e.g. this being when you specifically want to name the set {A, B, C} whose elements are A, B, and C). By the way, no one ever writes $i\neq j\neq k$ because it is not clear what is intended -- "$i\neq j$ and $j\neq k$" allows for the possibility that $i=k,$ which is probably not what is intended.

Comment: It would help if you describe exactly, in ordinary language (but in an unambiguous way), what it is you want to express mathematically. All I see is a sea of symbols, very few of which are defined. For example, what are $A,$ $B,$ $C$? Are these sets themselves, or index dummy variables? If so, why are you using $A,$ $B,$ $C$ and not simply $1,$ $2,$ $3$? Do you **really** want $e_A \neq e_B$ (you said **different** sets), or do you simply want to consider sets $e_A$ and $e_B$ (which may be different, but could also be equal)?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Ok, got it. So what I want to say is, there are the following sets, $e_A$,$e_B$,$e_C$ and I need to say, for example, $e_A \cap e_B \cap {e^c}_C$, $e_B \cap e_C \cap {e^c}_A$, $e_C \cap e_A \cap {e^c}_B$. Then how can I write this? ${e_{i}}\cap\ {e_{j}}\cap \ {{e^c}_{k}}
\ |_{i,j,k\in \{A,B,C\}\ \wedge\ i\neq j \wedge j\neq k \wedge i\neq k}$ maybe?